# Manually placing MySQL database files in the data folder - WAMP - XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp, wamp

I recently switched from using XAMPP to WAMP on my Windows 7 machine so I can do fast switching of PHP versions.

I completely uninstalled XAMPP, but first I backed up my htdocs, apache and mysql directories just in case.

After I installed WAMP and had everything up and running, I figured I could just drop some of my databases from my old XAMPP install into the "data" directory of the mysql directory in WAMP.

So that worked and the database shows up in phpMyadmin, but there are no tables. Is this a permissions thing? Like maybe I don't have the same user in the new install of mysql? Or am I missing something?

Am I allowed to just copy MySQL databases from one data folder to another or does it not work that way?

Both instances are using MySQL 5.5 (at least that's what both README files say in both MySQL directories).

THANKS

Comment: Are we talking MYISAM or INNODB tables here?

Comment: I'm not sure on that one. Its whatever the defaults are for XAMPP/WAMP. How do I find that out? Is it in the MySQL config file?

Comment: If you area phpMyAdmin user then click on the database name to get to the view that shows you all the tables within a database. Look at the `type` column.

Answer (score 1):

When using phpMyAdmin out of the box so to speak in WAMP, MYSQL is installed as per its default installation with the `root` userid setup to have NO PASSWORD.

Some people seem to think they should make one up when they see the login screen, is that what you are doing?

When you do this phpmyadmin allows you to APPEAR to login but then as you do not have root's privilages you see almost nothing on its other screens and are allowed to do nothing.

Use

```
username = root
password = (leave this blank)
```

Then set a password, there is a link on the next page it presents. AND DONT FORGET IT!!!!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I don't think that is the issue as I was never presented with a login. I just opened it up after the WAMP install and it opened right up. Also, phpMyadmin is working fine as far as being able to create new databases and import existing ones from a SQL script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This generally isn't a good idea. RiggsFolly was asking about your table type because some table types are more forgiving than others. Other possible trouble spots include file system permission problems or MySQL permission problems (as RiggsFolly asked).

I'd suggest to do an export (as an SQL file) and import that for a complete solution.